# React component abstraction confusion (componentDidMount)

Tags: reactjs

Using React, when we render a list of items and then insert an item to that list, the newly inserted item does not trigger componentDidMount

```
class Item extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.props.i)
  }

  render() {
    return (<div>something</div>)
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {items: []}

    this.prependItem = this.prependItem.bind(this)
  }

  prependItem() {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      return {items: [0, ...prevState.items]}
    })
  }

  render() {
    const {items} = this.state
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <button onClick={() => this.prependItem()}>+</button>
        {items.map((item, index) => {
          return (<Item key={index} i={index}/>)
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Using the above code, a natural expectation would be '0' whenever the button is clicked, but in truth the output is 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, ...

Essentially, the newly inserted item is treated as if it is exactly the same object as the previous item with that index, which can be unintuitive at times.

I guess a more direct question may be, how would I prepend an item to a list properly so that the componentDidMount for the new item (not the rest) would be triggered?

Comment: it's classic case of `key` misusing. in short: having identical element constructors React decide what component to update and what to create by `key` prop. So this way it update all N existing component and create single instead of just create item #0

Comment: take a look into good demo: https://medium.com/@vraa/why-using-an-index-as-key-in-react-is-probably-a-bad-idea-7543de68b17c and https://dev.to/jtonzing/the-significance-of-react-keys---a-visual-explanation--56l7

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! As an additional comment, having key equal to the array index does not actually update all N existing component. As usual, React compares the prev prop and state with the new prop and state, realizes that they are the same, and avoids updating/re-rendering for the first n items, n being the number of items before hitting the plus button. However, the new key (n+1) would tell React to update the new one.

Comment: it's until you don't use `this.props.i` in `render()`. when you do you will see all them are re-rendered and updated. `compare prev prop and state to new one` is  actual for `React.PureComponent` or custom `shouldComponentUpdate` but `React.Component` is dead simple here: re-render and compare anyway, if no difference - there will be no actual update.

Comment: Umm do you know of any acceptable ways of generating keys? (Other than say randomly generated long strings)

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/optimizing-performance.html#avoid-reconciliation will say better on performance and `PureComponent`

Comment: you better know your data. if you don't have anything like unique `id` then probably you should be fine even if it's re-renders in some way wrong order. if you do care about what component is re-created and what it's updated you probably relies on something else then just ordering in your expectations, right?

Comment: I changed the `render` function so that it contains `this.props.i`, and only one item is rerendered each time. As far as I know, React.Component still compares prop and state, ensuring that they are exactly equal, but React.PureComponent only does shallow comparisons, so that the same object with its fields mutated would be treated as the same object.

Comment: https://cdb.reacttraining.com/react-inline-functions-and-performance-bdff784f5578 this does a pretty good explanation too (best I've found), and why there's possibility for `PureComponent` to be slower than `Component`, due to double checking `shouldComponetUpdate`.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/embed/hungry-cerf-zf288 check browser's console, each item is re-rendered even when there is nothing actually to update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start with React's approach. It renders Virtual DOM and next compares it with real DOM to realize what element to update, what to delete and what to create.

React does not know *your intention* and to be stable/predictable it should be really straightforward. So React operates on 2 things: type(it's tag on browser level or component name in JSX)  and `key` prop.

Once both match - component will be updated. If any differs - and no other matches - then it will be delete + create.

There is really [complete article on reconciliation](https://uk.reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html) in ReactJS docs.

When you use `key={index}` and add element to the very beginning it ends up with updating all the elements except last one(since there was no component with such a `key` in DOM yet). And only last element is created while others are updated. Including that you've just inserted.

Also it should explain why use some random data for `key` is bad idea: you will never predict what component is updated or if random data is unique over the time all the component will be deleted and re-created on each render cycle. It'd be bottleneck for performance.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

function Item({ i }) {
  const inintialI = useRef(i);
  console.log(`rendered ${i}; initially it was ${initialI.current}`);
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(`created for ${i}`);
    return (() => {
      console.log(`deleted for ${i}`);
    })
  }, []);
  return <li>{i}</li>;
}

function App() {
  const [items, addItems] = useState([]);
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <button onClick={() => addItems(items => [items.length, ...items])}>
        +
      </button>
      <ul>
        {items.map((i, index) => (
          <Item key={index} i={i} />
        ))}
      </ul>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Here is short snippet(at [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/hungry-cerf-zf288)) that output in console when component is created and updated. So important things we are easier to ensure:

1. `React.Component` renders each time parent renders
2. with `key={index}` we will always re-created last item while we actually insert item into list at index #0.
3. all other items not only are re-rendered but actually are updated that is not good for perfomance